# Contradictory results about the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(2\pi n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

By observation, I can conclude that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(2\pi n)=\sin2\pi+\sin4\pi+\dots=0+0+\dots=0$$

using the fact that $\sin(2\pi n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

However, I also convinced myself that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(2\pi n)\neq0$$

by the following argument:

Suppose $\epsilon<1$ and there exists an $N>0$ such that $n>N$ implies $\lvert\sin(2\pi n)-0\rvert=\lvert\sin(2\pi n)\rvert<\epsilon<1$.
Since the period of $\sin(2\pi n)$ is $1$, then there exists some $x\in(N, N+1]$ such that $\lvert\sin(2\pi x)\rvert=1$ is not less than $\epsilon$.
The limit therefore cannot be $0$.

By the $n$-th term divergence test, this implies that my original series diverges.

Why are my conclusions contradictory? I tried Wolfram Alpha and the engine seems to suggest that the series both converges and diverges.

Comment: How did you convince yourself that that limit is non-zero? Can you state your argument?

Comment: The sequence $\bigl(\sin(2\pi n)\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is simply the null sequence. How did you prove that its limit is not $0$.

Comment: Please show your work in extremely clear detail that demonstrates the divergence.  This will allow MathSE reviewers to find and point out your mistake.

Comment: Edited to include an explanation. Should the limit I use in the divergence test also take the natural numbers as its "domain"?

Comment: The problem is that there is no $x$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $|\sin(2\pi x)| = 1$, so the fact that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin(2\pi x)$ does not exist is not in contradiction with the claim that $\lim_{n \to \infty, n \in \mathbb{N}} \sin(2\pi n) = 0$. Really, this seems to be an ambiguity in the notation, where the set on which $n$ is allowed to take values has not been fully clarified (is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or $n \in \mathbb{R}$?)

Answer (score 6):

There's an "implicit domain" issue going on. There are actually **two** functions at play here:

- $f: \color{red}{\mathbb{R}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}: x\mapsto \sin(2\pi x)$
- $g: \color{red}{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\sin(2\pi x)$.

These two functions have different domains (highlightedd in red), and this is crucial. When each claim is appropriately interpreted, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$$ is **false** but $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)=0$$ is **true**. For the $n$th term divergence test, it is the latter claim that is actually relevant, and we can see that this should be the case since when asking about $\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}f(i)$ it's obvious that only the behavior of $f$ on natural number inputs is relevant.

It may help at this point to state the relevant divergence test more clearly (to get the more familiar version of the test, take the contrapositive):

> Suppose $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}h(i)$ converges. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is some $N$ such that for every **integer** $n>N$ we have $\vert h(n)\vert<\epsilon$.

It should be clear, due to the explicitly bolded part (normally only implicit in the notation - specifically, the use of "$n$" as a free variable) that there is in fact no paradox of the type you are concerned about.